# How to remove padding from a JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

I'm trying to render button in one column of JTable.

### JTable renderer

```
private static class JTableButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {
    
    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -99465461909605968L;
    public JTableButtonRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
        // setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(110, 1110, 110, 110)));
        JButton button = (JButton) value;
        // button.setSize(100, 51);
        return button;
    }
}
```

This adds the JButton to the last column of my jTable as expected. But the cells in the last column have some padding. Is there any way to fill the cell (last column) with the button?

[image]

Comment: What is your current L&F?

Comment: The `value` parameter, in method `getTableCellRendererComponent` is a value from the [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). From the code in your question, it appears that your `TableModel` contains `JButton` objects. Is that correct? Any chance you could post a [mcve]?

Comment: @Rocco sorry for the delayed update, previously I was using  CDE/Motif as L&F now changed my L&F to windows. Thanks a lot for your pointer

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example, but if I just return a JButton in a renderer, without other settings it fills the cell space, so I cannot understand where the problem is, this is what I get:  [table with buttons](https://imgur.com/a/4XJj9sJ)